# How to prevent react context from adding duplicate item to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react context to add item to the cart and I want to prevent duplicate items being added in the cart, I have tried tweaking the code, but it seems like something is missed. Below is the code sample:

```
const cartReducer = (cartState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add-cart": {
      const item = action.payload;
      const existItem = cartState.cart.find((x) => x.id === item.id);

      if (existItem) {
        return {
          cart: [...cartState.cart, action.payload],
        };
      } else
        return {
          ...cartState,
          cart: [...cartState.cart, action.payload],
        };
    }
  }
};
```

```
export const CartProvider = (props) => {
  const [cartState, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    cart: [],
  });

  function addToCart(val) {
    dispatch({
      type: "add-cart",
      payload: val,
    });
  }
```

Comment: if condition should changed to.  `if (existItem) {  return cartState;  }` as you don't want to add the existing item in cart.

Comment: thanks man, i tried this changes, but now i can no longer add a new item to the cart. could there be something wrong with the function AddToCart ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you insert your item even if item already exists in the cart ?

You don't have to put your `action.payload` in the cart if already exists

```
 if (existItem) {
    return { ...cartState };
 } else {
    return {
       ...cartState,
       cart: [...cartState.cart, action.payload],
    };
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Young.  i tried this changes, but i can no longer add a new item to the cart. could there be something wrong with the function AddToCart ?

Comment: @Yusuf your function looks OK, can you show me how you are using it ?

Comment: thanks, here is it    <button onClick={() => CART.addToCart(product.id)}>.... what i could noticed is the "existItem" is always true once i add the first item

Comment: @Yusuf - Is it because you are always sending the same Id?

Comment: thanks. its working now, my problem was the "existItem" ...the corrected is "  const existItem = cartState.cart.find((x) => x === item);"